# Request Validation Not Working for PUT method In Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-request

My Route

```
Route::put('dataedit/{id}', [empDataController::class, 'empDataEdit'])->middleware('guest')->name('emp.data.edit');
```

My Controller

```
public function empDataEdit(empDataValidation $request, $id){

        $id = Crypt::decrypt($id);

        $DataAddCheck = EmpData::find($id)->update($request->all());
        if($DataAddCheck){
            return back()->with('successMsg', 'Data Added Successfully');
        }
        else{
            return back()->with('successMsg', 'Something Went Wrong Try Again!');
        }
    }
```

Note : I add use *App\Http\Requests\empDataValidation;* in controller Top.

My Request Validation

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class empDataValidation extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'empName' => ['required'],
        ];
    }
}
```

My blade (Just Important part)

```
<form id="msform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                    action="{{ route('emp.data.edit', Crypt::encrypt($data->id)) }}">
                    @csrf
                    @method('PUT')
```

Note: When I use  `Request $request` in controller It works Fine but when I use `empDataValidation $request` It not working, In my create controller `empDataValidation $request`works fine. Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: can you try ```update($request->validated());```

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Does it throw an exception or just return the error message you catch manually?

Comment: You are using which version of Laravel?

Comment: Laravel V8 @MrEduar

Comment: no error through it redirect into the same page @kenny-horna

Comment: in `[empDataValidation::class, 'rules']` do `dd($this->all())` before the `return` line and share the output